# Conda update python wants to update other packages, not python

Tags: python, conda

I have a `conda` environment running Python 3.7.5. I tried updating it to the latest version (3.8.0) but it wants to update other packages (even downgrade `scipy`), and says nothing about upgrading Python.

Why is this happening?

```
(workenv) $ conda update python
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/workenv

  added / updated specs:
    - python


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    blas-1.0                   |         openblas          46 KB
    certifi-2019.9.11          |           py37_0         154 KB
    libopenblas-0.3.6          |       h5a2b251_2         7.7 MB
    numpy-1.17.4               |   py37hd5be1e1_0           4 KB
    numpy-base-1.17.4          |   py37h2f8d375_0         4.1 MB
    scipy-1.3.1                |   py37he2b7bc3_0        14.0 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        26.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  libopenblas        pkgs/main/linux-64::libopenblas-0.3.6-h5a2b251_2

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  intel-openmp-2019.4-243
  mkl-2019.4-243
  mkl-service-2.3.0-py37he904b0f_0
  mkl_fft-1.0.15-py37ha843d7b_0
  mkl_random-1.1.0-py37hd6b4f25_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  blas                                              1.0-mkl --> 1.0-openblas
  ca-certificates    conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.9.1~ --> pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2019.10.16-0
  numpy                               1.17.3-py37hd14ec0e_0 --> 1.17.4-py37hd5be1e1_0
  numpy-base                          1.17.3-py37hde5b4d6_0 --> 1.17.4-py37h2f8d375_0
  openssl            conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1d-h516909a_0 --> pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1d-h7b6447c_3

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi                                       conda-forge --> pkgs/main

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  scipy                                1.3.1-py37h7c811a0_0 --> 1.3.1-py37he2b7bc3_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Comment: What about `conda install python=3.8`?

Answer (score 0):

It's might check and install the dependencies of python before installing the python update itself. (You could check it by comparing the dependencies list of the different python versions.)

If the newest version of python is incompatible with the newest version of scipy, it will install an older version of scipy to make sure it will run stable.